# Как в Python мне самому изменить переменную во время работы программы в цикле?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Всем привет.

Не очень уверен как это правильно сформулировать, прошу подсказать если это как то называется.

У меня есть цикл `for file in os.listdir()`, цикл гоняет запуск subprocess с продолжительной работой другой программы.

Сам код работает, но мне было бы интересно иметь возможность не просто остановить выполнение кода в момент нажатия, а сделать какой то способ, чтобы программа продолжила работать, но остановилась в предусмотренный момент, что то вроде:

1. Я запускаю код. Код начинает работать.
2. Код доделывает 1й проход цикла. Код делает проверку флага, если флаг False - проверка ничего не делает и цикл естественно переключается на 2й файл цикла for. Потом на третий и.т.п.
3. Я сам, вручную делаю **что то как то**, в любой момент исполнения программы, когда мне приспичит, и флаг становится True. Но меня не устраивает простой input, который жестко фиксирован и будет останавливать программу пока я не введу туда что то, программа должна работать без прерываний до тех пор, пока я не сделаю **что то как то**.
4. В конце очередного прохода, флаг True, проверка срабатывает, и программа заканчивается.

Собственно, есть ли какой то способ сделать это самое **что то как то** чтобы не грохнуть программу сразу, а именно переключить флаг внутри программы, а дальше уже сама программа обработала этот флаг в нужный момент?

Использую python 3.9 через PyCharm community последнего апдейта.

**Update 1:** видимо нужно уточнить. У меня есть цикл. В цикле я делаю целую кучу разных действий. Как до запуска subprocess, так и после. Мне, как минимум, надо убедиться, что та, другая программа запускаемая через subprocess, отработала без ошибок... Если я жмякаю кнопку стоп в pycharm'е, оно прерывается прям вот в тот же момент. Мне же нужно прерваться не тогда, когда была нажата кнопка. И даже не сразу после отработки subprocess'а. Мне нужно прерваться именно тогда, когда нужно прерваться **мне**, и при этом сделать именно те действия, которые **мне** нужно чтобы сделало при этом прерывании.

Comment: предложение.сделайте на ткинтере кнопки старт/стоп для нужных вам процессов. рядом можно запилить lable в которой будут писаться промежуточные результаты или другая инфа. так вы сможите контролировать всё.

Comment: Уууу, сложна... Кто такой tkinter и кто его съел? PS я, конечно, почитаю про то как перебить прогу из консольной в гуишную, но... СЛОЖНААА... PS оффтоп, а почему ваш ответ идет не так как идут ответы Влада? Почему нету голосовалки и.т.п.?

Comment: ткинтер это не сложно. ну и даже если вам будет сложно, но это решит ваш вопрос

Comment: это не ответ, просто комментарий. ответ нужно оформлять и писать код.мне лень.

Comment: А, понятно. Спасибо. Пойду читать про ткинтер и про то как под него переделать консольную прогу.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону модуля multiprocessing и/или используйте потоки (threading)

Comment: Ага, спасибо, почитаю